# Custom constraints in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have the below table

```
 Column   |           Type           |                        Modifiers                        
-----------+--------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------
 id        | integer                  | not null default nextval('votes_vote_id_seq'::regclass)
 voter     | character varying        | 
 votee     | character varying        | 
 timestamp | timestamp with time zone | default now()
```

Currently ,  i have a unique constraint with `voter` and `votee` meaning that there is only 1 vote per user

I would like to enforce a condition which allows votes to happen weekly using the timestamp column. A User can only vote for the votee only once a week.

Is there a way i can add custom constraints to postgres? Are they the same thing as functions?

Answer (score 0):

A constraint is something like a special trigger in PostgreSQL.

Normal triggers won't do, because they cannot see concurrent modifications of the database, so two concurrent transactions could both see their condition fulfilled, but after they commit, the condition might be violated.

The solution I'd recommend is to use `SERIALIZABLE` transactions throughout (*everybody*, including readers, has to use them for it to work) and verify your condition in a `BEFORE` trigger.
`SERIALIZABLE` will guarantee that the above scenario cannot happen.